# ClassCastException with generic varargs?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic interface

```
{
void evaluate( TYPE... things );
}
```

I have a generic method with the signature

```
<TYPE> void genericmethod( INTERFACE<TYPE> interfase, TYPE thing )
{
//the following line throws the ClassCastException
interfase.evaluate( thing );
}
```

PCard is a name in my project.

So the call in the end is

```
INTERFACE<PCard> interfase = new WorkingImplementation<PCard>();
PCard pcard = new PCard();
```

this seems to throw a ClassCastException in the genericmethod, when it tries to call turn the single pcard into a varargs array.

```
genericmethod( interfase, pcard );
```

The problem is relieved when there is no call to a genericmethod and you just call the interface directly.

```
interfase.evaluate( pcard );
```

What causes the Exception (internally)?     (my personal guess is java is overwhelmed)

the Exception message:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Llib.cardgame.CG$PCard; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [Llib.cardgame.CG$PCard; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE]? (Preferably, one without classes called `INTERFACE` ... *shudder* ...)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  Generics and arrays don’t mix.  Use `List<? extends TYPE> things` instead.

Generics are merely a compiler trick.  They don’t exist at runtime.  Arrays have a distinct type at runtime, like `String[]` or `Number[]`.  But since a generic type doesn’t exist at runtime, it’s not possible for the compiler to generate code that will make an array of a generic type.  (A call to a varargs method creates an array implicitly to hold the varargs arguments.)

In your case, the compiler emits a warning about this, and generates code that’s as close to what you want as possible:  the generated code for the implicit array that is created whenever a varargs method is called will be `Object[]` (since `TYPE`, I’m guessing, has no upper bound).

If you turn on all compiler warnings, you will be notified of this.  Addressing all compiler warnings properly (meaning, do not use `@SuppressWarnings`) will guarantee that you won’t get obscure surprises like the one you’re getting now.

I recommend [Gilad Bracha’s generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/).  I have found it invaluable for understanding how generics work.

Comment: And if that tutorial is not enough, and you want a challenge and question your own understanding of generics, dive deeper into that via http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html :-D

Comment: This far I know about. My question was concerning why wrapping the generic interface call into another generic method causes the code to break, while directly calling the generic varargs works. Something is done differently between both cases.

Comment: Because when you have `INTERFACE<PCard> interfase`, the compiler sees that the type is PCard and generates the method call as `interfase.evaluate(new PCard[] { pcard });`.  But inside the body of `genericmethod`, `<TYPE>` could be anything, so the compiler can only generate the method call as `interfase.evaluate(new Object[] { thing });`.  There is no safe workaround that involves varargs;  just use a List.

Comment: So really the lesson here is that Java Arrays and Generics do not match very well, the compiler is already trying its hardest just to make it work at run time, and even when I want to try to make it work it probably won't, so I just have to take the L and use less performant code.